# How to change this basic SQL statement to PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am looking for my DBMS window to read Average Salary: $2,843.76 I have a simple SQL statement and I am wondering how to have it display in the dbms output.
I was thinking something along these lines..

```
dbms_output.put_line('Average Salary = ' (salary))


SELECT avg(salary) avg_salary 
FROM    employee;
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need an anonymous block if you're running from PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  avgSalary NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT avg(salary) into avgSalary FROM employee;
  DBMS_Output.Put_Line('Average Salary = ' || avgSalary);
END;
/
```

And don't forget that with DBMS_Output you need to `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`. I know I usually do :)